# How can I programmatically expand the notifications bar in my android app?

Tags: android, notifications

I found the following piece of code from the adw launcher:

```
Object service = launcher.getSystemService("statusbar");
if (service != null) {
    Method expand = service.getClass().getMethod("expand");
    expand.invoke(service);
}
```

Which throws a SecurityException: StatusBarManagerService: Neither user 123456 nor current process has android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR

So I added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
```

to my application manifest.xml, But still no luck

Comment: What do you mean 'no luck'? Are you saying that after adding that permission, it still tells you that you don't have the permission? Or do you have a different error?

Comment: @tim, sorry It's still throwing the exact same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object service = getSystemService( "statusbar" );
Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName( "android.app.StatusBarManager" );
Method expand = statusbarManager.getMethod( "expand" );
expand.invoke( service );
```

and add this to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
```

Comment: Where to add the object snippet in code?Can you please explain with more detail.